# is there any way for partial payment with booking Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using rooms Module and I need to implement a way user can pay some amount while booking and pending after the trip/booking completed or user going for checkout . So I try different ways but nothing get fit to the requirement . Is there any way in drupal 7 rooms module we can implement the first some percentage and then pending payment after the trip over.

Please give your suggestions.

Thanks